# Adding the taxonomy before the custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, rewrite-rules

I have a custom post type named `landings` which has a rewrite rule to change the slug to loans and a custom taxonomy `provinces` and I want the custom post type to have the slug of the province in the permalink.

Basically I want it to be something like this:

```
/loans --> Custom WordPress Page
/loans/alberta --> Show the taxonomy Alberta (taxonomy-provinces.php)
/loans/alberta/calgary --> Show the landing of Calgary (single-landings.php)
```

### Landings

```
register_post_type('landings', array(
    'label' => 'Landings',
    'public' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'loans/%province%',
        'with_front' => false
    )
));
```

### Provinces

```
register_taxonomy('provinces', array('landings'), array(
    'label' => 'Provinces',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'loans',
        'with_front' => false
    )
));
```

I've tried to apply the `post_type_link` filter to replace the `%province%` in the admin and it works fine for the backend, however when I try to access it via the front I get a 404.

```
add_filter('post_type_link', function($link, $post = null){

    if($post instanceof WP_Post && $post->post_type == 'landings'){

        if($province = get_field('province', $post->ID))
            return str_replace('%province%', $province->slug, $link);

    }

    return $link;

}, 1, 2);
```

So to continue, I've updated the rewrite rules of WordPress:

```
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', function($wpRewrite){

    $rules = array();
    $postTypes = get_post_types(array('name' => 'landings', 'public' => true, '_builtin' => false), 'objects');
    $taxonomies = get_taxonomies(array('name' => 'provinces', 'public' => true, '_builtin' => false), 'objects');

    // Loop through each post type
    foreach($postTypes as $postType){

        $name = $postType->name;
        $slug = $postType->rewrite['slug'];

        // Loop through each taxonomy
        foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy){

            // Proceed to next taxonomy
            if($taxonomy->object_type[0] != $name)
                continue;

            $terms = get_categories(array('type' => $name, 'taxonomy' => $taxonomy->name, 'hide_empty' => false));

            // Loop through each term to create the right rewrite rule
            foreach($terms as $term){

                $rules[str_replace('%province%', $term->slug, $slug) . '/?$'] = 'index.php?' . $term->taxonomy . '=' . $term->slug;

            }

        }

    }

    $wpRewrite->rules = $rules + $wpRewrite->rules;

});
```

With the rewrite rules above, I managed to get the `/loans` and `/loans/alberta` working properly. However, when I visit `/loans/alberta/calgary` I get a 404 even though in the admin when I edit Calgary, I see the permalink: `/loans/alberta/calgary`.

Also, when I scroll down to the Yoast SEO module, I see that the link is `/calgary` but when I try to access that permalink, I still get another 404.

Comment: do you define the rewrite tag `%province%` anywhere? your taxonomy slug is `provinces`, plural.

Comment: @Milo Oh wow silly me. But now when I do `/loans/ontario/calgary` it works even though it shouldn't since the post object `Calgary` has the province `Alberta` as a taxonomy and not `Ontario` :o

Comment: Yeah, it won't add the tax query on its own. If you want to prevent that, you have to hook `pre_get_posts` and add the taxonomy parameters.